# Django Model isn't migrating even after i saved and added app to installedApps

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user = get_user_model

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        user,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

---

When I run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Then shows:

```
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\djangomodels\I4G006918VEO> python manage.py migrate 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Comment: Did you create migrations? `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: @yjay yes i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `user=get_user_model()` not <s>`user=get_user_model`</s>.

It returns the `User` model that is active in this project.

Try this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        user,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then, run both the commands as `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.